# SPARK YARN: cannot send job from client (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032)

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I'm trying to send spark job to yarn (without HDFS) in HA mode.

For submitting I'm using `org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit`.
When I send request from machine with active Resource Manager, it works well. But if I' trying to send from machine with standby Resource Manager, job fails with error:

```
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Connecting to spark2-node-dev/10.10.10.167:8032
DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Connecting to /0.0.0.0:8032
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep
```

However, when I send request via command line (spark-submit), it works well through both active and standby machine.

What can cause the problem?

P.S. Use the same parameters for both type of sending job: `org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit` and `spark-submit` command line request. And properties `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm_id` defined for all rm hosts

Comment: If I had to guess, your app might not be using the same `yarn-site.xml` as `spark-submit`. Also, when you say _`yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm_id`_ you do actually mean `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.**<rm_id>**`, right? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html#Configurations

Comment: Yes, I used `yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.**<rm_id>**`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with absence of yarn-site.xml within class path for spark-submitter jar. Actually spark submitter jar does not take to account `YARN_CONF_DIR` or `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` env var, so cannot see yarn-site.

One solution that I found was to put yarn-site into classpath of jar.